# Anyone had any luck integrating SQL unit tests to run with CI build tool?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, build, continuous-integration

Goal is to run a few queries against a database on each new build? Has anyone had any luck without having to put sql in java classes or creating entire new schemas to hold stored procs? Ideally you can include some SQLs in separate files that get run as soon as the build completes.

Might be using maven,bamboo but would love to hear any experiences/successes/difficulties that people have encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what tools you use for writing you SQL unit tests.  If you're using Steven Feuerstein's utplsql tool you should read this artcle on [Continuous Integration with Oracle PL/SQL, utPLSQL and Hudson](http://www.theserverlabs.com/blog/2009/05/18/continuous-integration-with-oracle-plsql-utplsql-and-hudson/).  And even if you're not it might provide some useful insights.

Comment: +1 for info. Sorry, my question is quite brief. I'm not using a tool to write SQL unit tests, these are done manually in a text editor. It is not PL/SQL that I'm trying to test it is basically the existence of certain tables, columns, record counts.etc I have had a look at utplsql but it requires creating a new schema which I would like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Team City (Jetbrains) is what you're looking for. It has various build runners, including but not limited to Ant, MS Build, NUnit, Maven and Command Line.

Just configure a TC-project to listen to your svn/git/hg repository for changes, then run a build: first compilation and if successful then Maven (or whatever). Or which-ever way you want to do it.

/mikkel

Comment: How do the sql tests come into this?

Comment: Yeah, I just re-read the question and your clarification. I Guess TC doesn't help executing "raw" sql tests the way you want. 

I would wrap my tests in an NUnit (or equivalent) module and have TC run it for me. Have to store the sql somewhere, may as well be the version control repository.